# convert a function into rxjs observable

Tags: rxjs

Imaging I have this code

```
function sayHi(){
  console.log("hi")
}
sayHi();
sayHi();
sayHi();
sayHi();
sayHi();
```

Above code will log `hi` 5 times

But I want to use `debounce` operator and log it only once in every 1 sec.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Not sure I understand how this is related to rxjs. Maybe you need simple non-reactive https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce ?

Answer (score 0):

what about `internal` function: e.g.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

const source = interval(1000).subscribe(val => console.log('hi'));
```

[link to docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html)

----- Edited -----

Lets try something else:

`hi$` will be `Subject<void>` and we will be subscribe to him to console something

```js
hi$.pipe(...).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('hi');
});
```

Let's define some function for calling `hi$` subject. this can be called any time in any amount.

```js
let fn = () => {
  hi$.next();
  // ...
}
```

Last think is filter console.log to force it to run only once per second. For this i recommend `throttle` operator, `debounce` stop calling subscriber for some time, so:

```js
hi$.pipe(throttle(1000)).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('hi');
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't even try to answer the question. I am not asking for operator recommendations. Question is, I believe, very clear. I have a function which i want to run only once in few seconds.

Comment: Pls check edited section, I hope thats solution that you're looking for

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services Your question is not clear at all. And the OP's answer does run the function every x seconds.